# Default UIPickerView height

Tags: iphone, size, uipickerview

How can I programatically obtain the default height of an UIPickerView instance, in accordance to the resolution and orientation of the device that the app is currently running on?

I would like not to use a hardcoded value for this parameter, in the event that new devices will support different screen resolutions and thus will determine this component to have a different default size.

Comment: You could use the intrinsicContentSize.height property on UIPickerView

Answer (score 16):

The warning that André saw doesn't seem to happen anymore (Xcode 4.2; iOS SDK 5.0).  If you create it with `initWithFrame` and give it a height of zero, you can then read back it's height from the `frame.height` property:

```
uiPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 77, 320, 0)];
DLog(@"uiPickerView=%@",uiPickerView);
```

gives:

```
uiPickerView=<UIPickerView: 0x9a28c40; frame = (0 77; 320 216); layer = <CALayer: 0x9a28d00>>
```

So 216 is the default height.

I couldn't find a definition for this in the headers, so reading it back seems to be the safest way.

It is possible to set a frame with a non-zero height, but Apple say don't do that, and it seems to cause rendering problems.

Comment: on an iPhone in portrait, 216 is still correct (as of iOS 10 and iPhone 7). In landscape, however, it's 162 when I print the frame.

Answer (score 3):

With auto layout I was wondering the same due to the fact that you can't pin to the bottom of it.

The default height with no changes to an UIPickerView is `216px`[image: ** UIPickerView**]

Answer (score 2):

If you create an instance with a height of 0, it will be overridden with the appropriate default height, and you can just get its `frame.size.height`.

However, on iPad this will issue a warning (tested a few days ago). I eventually had to use hardcoded values for iPad...

P.S. This was for a UIDatePicker; not sure if it's the exact same thing for UIPickerView.

Comment: Is there any possible way that doesn't issue warnings? It seems rather hacky to resort to a system coercion for adding a component that is recommended to have a default size.

Comment: Just for clarification, this "warning" I mentioned is simply a message that the system prints to the console. This warning includes the suggested default height, which was the hardcoded value I ended up setting on my code. If you do that, you don't get any warnings. An like I said, if you set the default to 0 (and then read the value set by the system) you won't get these warnings on iPhone/iPod, it's only on iPad.

Comment: I received the warning messages on iPhone too, on iOS 4.2, informing me that the size of the control has been defaulted to its proper size.

Answer (score 1):

In 2022 it is 162.  Pic is not touching the height just pulling into IB [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the frame property of the uipickerview.